# Cannot find name 'Persistence'. Did you mean 'setPersistence'?ts

Tags: typescript, firebase-authentication

I cannot get my google firebase auth to work,  I get the following error `Cannot find name 'Persistence'. Did you mean 'setPersistence'?ts(2552)`

Here is my code.  I tried to import it but still gets an error.  This is in TypeScript where do I import from?  It appears UserCredential and Persistence are both an interface.

```
import { initializeApp, FirebaseApp, FirebaseError } from 'firebase/app';
    import {getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, Auth, signInWithPopup, UserCredential, setPersistence } from "firebase/auth";
   
    export interface IUser {
        displayName: string | null;
        email: string | null;
        providerId: string;
        uid: string;
    }
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "apiKey",
        authDomain: "authDomain",
        databaseURL: "databaseURL",
        projectId: "projectId",
        storageBucket: "storeageBucket",
        messagingSenderId: "messageSenderId",
        appId: "appId",
        measurementId: "measurmentId"
    };
   
    const _getApp = (): FirebaseApp => {
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'MyExample');
        return app;
    }
    
    const _setPeristence = async (): Promise<void> => {
        const app = _getApp();
        const auth = getAuth(app);
        setPersistence(auth, Persistence.LOCAL);
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    
    const _signInWithProvider = async (resolve:any): Promise<void> =>{
        const currentUser = await GetGoogleUser()
        if (currentUser != null) {
            return resolve();
        }
        else {
            const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
            provider.addScope('profile');
            provider.addScope('email');
            const auth = getAuth(_getApp());
            signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
                .then((result: UserCredential) => {
                }).catch((error: FirebaseError) => {                       
                });
        }
    }
    
    const SignIn = async (resolve: any): Promise<void> => {
        await _setPeristence();
        _signInWithProvider(resolve);
        return;
    }
    
    export {       
        SignIn,
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The definition of `Persistence` is

```
interface Persistence {
    /**
     * Type of Persistence.
     * - 'SESSION' is used for temporary persistence such as `sessionStorage`.
     * - 'LOCAL' is used for long term persistence such as `localStorage` or `IndexedDB`.
     * - 'NONE' is used for in-memory, or no persistence.
     */
    readonly type: 'SESSION' | 'LOCAL' | 'NONE';
}
```

It's not an enum, but an object interface with a `type` property that can be either `'SESSION'`, `'LOCAL'`, or `'NONE'`. You can just pass an object literal with the desired `type` to `setPersistence`:

```
setPersistence(auth, {type: 'LOCAL'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add the following to the import

```
browserLocalPersistence,
browserSessionPersistence,
inMemoryPersistence
```

like so

```
    import {
    getAuth, 
    GoogleAuthProvider, 
    Auth, 
    signInWithPopup, 
    UserCredential, 
    setPersistence,
    browserLocalPersistence,
    browserSessionPersistence,
    inMemoryPersistence
 } from "firebase/auth";
```